# Angular Change Detection with Observable timer

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

**Background:**

I have a number of components in my Angular 6 application that are required to display the current time (hh:mm).

These were initially implemented using `setInterval` with `this.now` being bound in the view:

```
setInterval(() => {
   this.now = new Date();
}, 1000);
```

Naturally, this causes change detection to run every second which is wasteful given the value will only update once per minute. I can improve this by running the `setInterval` outside of `ngZone` and manually triggering change detection if the minute has rolled over.

**Question:**

I'm trying to implement an observable stream of dates which emit a new value every minute. This is what I have do far...

```
timer(0, 1000)
  .pipe(
    map(() => new Date()),
    distinctUntilChanged((a: Date, b: Date) => a.getMinutes() === b.getMinutes()),
    tap(date => console.log(date))
  );
```

A new date is emitted once per minute however subscribing to this stream causes Angular's change detection to run every second. (I confirmed this by adding a `ngDoCheck` to a component that subscribe).

How can I defer change detection so it only occurs when a new value is emitted?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Change detection usually happens in a recursion loop

Comment: Did you try ```Observable.interval(1000)``` ?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear: "I'm trying to implement an observable stream of dates which emit a new value every minute." however I only want change detection to trigger when a value is emitted, not every 1000ms when the timer fires.

Comment: run it outside angular zone and set manual changing for value: https://blog.angularindepth.com/boosting-performance-of-angular-applications-with-manual-change-detection-42cb396110fb

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subject and interval for this i guess maybe some way like this :

Basically in your code where you have implemented this(assuming it is a separate service : `some.service.ts` ) , define a subject like this :

```
someSubject : Subject<Date> = new Subject<Date>();

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    map(() => new Date()),
    distinctUntilChanged((a: Date, b: Date) => a.getMinutes() === b.getMinutes()),
    tap(date => {
       console.log(date);
       this.someSubject.next(date);
       });
  ).subscribe();
```

Subscribe to the `someSubject` from wherever you want to listen to the date change like this :

```
this._someService.someSubject.subscribe((date : Date) =>{
 console.log(date); //you'll have a new date object everytime your date object changes i.e everyminute
});
```

don't forget to import `interval` from `rxjs`

i have created an example(listen for every second change) using StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ytdbs

Comment: Thanks for your example, however it is still triggering change detection every second. I'm trying to "defer change detection so it only occurs when a new value is emitted". So once per minute, rather than once per second.  
I have updated your example with what I have:  
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbay8g

Comment: @MS_AU how is it triggering a change detection every second ? a timer or an interval emits an observable based on the value you've pushed

Comment: Angular's change detection is triggered in response to asynchronous tasks. In the case of a `timer` or `interval` Observable change detection will occur after the specified delay, every second (1000ms) in my case. Given I was piping the emitted values through a `map` and `distinctUntilChanged` operator - a new value is only emitted once per minute, not once per second. However, change detection _still_ occurs every second.  This question is specifically around the best practices for deferring change detection with Observable timers.

Comment: @MS_AU you can reattach and detach the change detection using ``changeDetectionStrategy.detach()`` and ``changeDetectionStartegy.reattach()`` and also set changeDetectionStrategy to onPush . i have the plunker updated but it seems like ngDoCheck is called anyways which shouldn't be the case